# How to silence an executable with optional input run via subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: python, stream, stdin, io-redirection, gams-math

I have an issue with a call to the `gams` executable for the General Algebraic Modeling System (GAMS), available as a free trial version [here](https://www.gams.com/download/).

In an application I am building, I call this executable and others through a function that has a switch to silence output by redirecting to `dev/null`, essentially:

```py
def syscall(executable, *args, silent=False):
    """Issue a system call.

    Arguments
    ---------
    executable : str
        the name of the executable to be called. Needs to be an executable in
        one of the directories listed in the PATH environment variable.
    args : list of str
        the arguments passed to the executable
    silent : bool
        whether the output should be hidden from stdout (default: False)

    Returns
    -------
    ret : int
        the return code of the system call
    """
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    import sys

    if silent:
        process = Popen([executable, *args], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                             stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    else:
        process = Popen([executable, *args], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
    process.wait()  # wait until executable has finished
    ret = process.returncode
    return ret
```

While this works charmingly with any other executable, `gams` just doesn't want to be quiet, i.e., `syscall('gams', silent=True)` and `syscall('gams', 'Problem.gms', silent=True)` still gives output.
When trying this in an interactive interpreter I realized that appears to be because `gams` allows for input from `stdin`!

Is there any way of preloading stdin in order to avoit output?

Comment: `Popen()` accepts an optional `stdin=` keyword argument you could set to `None`.

Comment: @martineau Nope, `p1 = subprocess.Popen(['gams', 'Rosenbrok.gms'], stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)` still gives output!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of output do you actually see? And what version of GAMS are you using? Older version wrote to console (if available) by default instead of stdOut. You could change that by setting the parameter `logOption` (see https://www.gams.com/32/docs/UG_GamsCall.html#GAMSAOlogoption) to `3`, if your GAMS version is not the latest. Or, maybe better, since you don't want the output anyway, set `logOption=0` to suppress the output right away.